Error Creating Thread in Azure OpenAI Assistant - "Failed to create file operation"
I am trying to use the Azure OpenAI Assistant with the file search tool. I successfully uploaded the files and created a vector store, but I encounter a 500 - server_error when attempting to create a thread. Here is the relevant part of my code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from azure_client import configure_azure_client, create_assistant, create_vector_store, upload_files
from openai import AssistantEventHandler
import time

# Initialize FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
filename = "incidentes_ficticios2.json"

# Configure Azure OpenAI client
print("10. Configuring Azure OpenAI client...")
client = configure_azure_client()

# Create assistant
print("11. Creating assistant...")
assistant = create_assistant(client)

# Create vector store
print("12. Creating vector store...")
vector_store = create_vector_store(client)

# Upload files to vector store
print("13. Uploading files to vector store...")
file_batch = upload_files(client, vector_store, [filename])

# Polling to ensure files are processed
print("14. Checking file processing status...")
while True:
    file_batch = client.beta.vector_stores.file_batches.retrieve(file_batch.id)
    if file_batch.status == 'completed':
        print("15. Files successfully processed.")
        break
    elif file_batch.status == 'failed':
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="File processing failed.")
    print("15a. Waiting for files to process...")
    time.sleep(5)

# Update assistant with vector store
print("16. Updating assistant with vector store...")
assistant = client.beta.assistants.update(
    assistant_id=assistant.id,
    tool_resources={"file_search": {"vector_store_ids": [vector_store.id]}},
)
print("17. Assistant updated with vector store.")

# Define request model
class QueryRequest(BaseModel):
    query: str

# Event handler class
class EventHandler(AssistantEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = None

    def on_text_created(self, text):
        print("18. Assistant created text:", text)
        self.response = text

    def on_tool_call_created(self, tool_call):
        print("19. Tool call created:", tool_call.type)

    def on_message_done(self, message):
        print("20. Assistant processed message:", message.content)

# Endpoint to query assistant
@app.post("/query")
async def query_assistant(request: QueryRequest):
    try:
        print("21. Query received:", request.query)

        # Create message file
        print("22. Creating message file...")
        try:
            message_file = client.files.create(
                file=open(filename, "rb"), purpose="assistants"
            )
            print("23. Message file created:", message_file.id)
        except Exception as e:
            print("23a. Error creating message file:", str(e))
            raise

        # Read file content for debugging
        try:
            with open(filename, "r") as f:
                file_content = f.read()
                print("23b. File content:", file_content[:1000])
        except Exception as e:
            print("23c. Error reading file for debugging:", str(e))
            raise

        # Check assistant and vector store resources
        print("23d. Assistant resources:", assistant.tool_resources)
        print("23e. Vector store ID:", vector_store.id)

        # Create thread with user message
        print("24. Creating thread...")
        try:
            thread = client.beta.threads.create(
                messages=[
                    {
                        "role": "user",
                        "content": request.query,
                        "attachments": [
                            {"file_id": message_file.id, "tools": [{"type": "file_search"}]}
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            )
            print("25. Thread created:", thread.id)
        except Exception as e:
            print("25a. Error creating thread:", str(e))
            print("25b. Message details:", {
                "role": "user",
                "content": request.query,
                "attachments": [
                    {"file_id": message_file.id, "tools": [{"type": "file_search"}]}
                ],
            })
            raise

        # Initialize event handler to capture events
        event_handler = EventHandler()

        # Execute assistant stream
        print("26. Executing assistant stream...")
        try:
            with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
                thread_id=thread.id,
                assistant_id=assistant.id,
                instructions=request.query,
                event_handler=event_handler,
            ) as stream:
                stream.until_done()
        except Exception as e:
            print("26a. Error executing assistant stream:", str(e))
            raise

        # Check if assistant provided a response
        if event_handler.response is None:
            print("27. No response from assistant.")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="No response from assistant")

        print("28. Assistant response:", event_handler.response)
        return {"response": event_handler.response}
    except Exception as e:
        print("29. Error processing query:", str(e))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

# Start Uvicorn server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("30. Starting Uvicorn server...")
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

Error Logs:
23a. Erro ao criar thread: Error code: 500 - {'error': {'message': 'Failed to create file operation.', 'type': 'server_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
23b. Detalhes da mensagem: {'role': 'user', 'content': 'tem bug?', 'attachments': [{'file_id': 'assistant-YHnvnwCKLeGoKe7ySvGqUDqP', 'tools': [{'type': 'file_search'}]}]}
27. Erro ao processar consulta: Error code: 500 - {'error': {'message': 'Failed to create file operation.', 'type': 'server_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

I have confirmed that the file content is correct and the vector store has been updated successfully. What could be causing this issue when creating a thread? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.
